# Socketio seems to launch a new thread each time it receives a message

Tags: python, websocket, socket.io

Socketio seems to launche a new thread each time it receives a message.
Is this normal behavior?
CPU load seems high.

```
# coding: utf-8
import json, sys, time, traceback, os, threading, socketio, operator
from datetime import datetime

class WebSocket():
    def __init__(self, logger=None):
        self.url = URL
        self.logger = logger

    def run(self, channels={}):
        self.channels = channels
        self.sio = socketio.Client(reconnection=True, reconnection_attempts=0, reconnection_delay=1, reconnection_delay_max=30, logger=False)
        self.sio.on('connect', self.on_connect)
        self.sio.on('message', self.on_message)
        self.sio.connect(self.url, transports=['websocket'])

    def on_connect(self):
        self.logger.debug('WS: on_connect')
        for channel_name in self.channels.keys():
            self.logger.debug(f"WS: join {channel_name}")
            self.sio.emit('join-room', channel_name)

    def on_message(self, msg):
        if "message" in msg and "data" in msg["message"]:
            room = msg["room_name"]
            self.channels[room]("message")    # call handler


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import my_util

    logger = my_util.get_custom_logger("websocket.log")

    def handler(msg):
        logger.debug(f"handler: {msg}")

    channels = {
        "channel_name": handler
    }
    ws = WebSocket(logger=logger)
    ws.run(channels)
    while True:
        time.sleep(9999)
```

Log shows thread number increments.
`log_stream_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(fmt="%(levelname).1s,%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d %(threadName)s %(message)s", datefmt="%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S"))`

D,20230707 09:20:56.505 Thread-4 (_handle_eio_message) handler: message
D,20230707 09:20:56.872 Thread-5 (_handle_eio_message) handler: message
D,20230707 09:20:57.229 Thread-6 (_handle_eio_message) handler: message
D,20230707 09:20:57.591 Thread-7 (_handle_eio_message) handler: message
D,20230707 09:20:58.030 Thread-8 (_handle_eio_message) handler: message